# Magento get unsalted md5 password

Tags: magento, md5, password-encryption

I'm trying to migrate the data in magento to another database in which I store the passwords with a normal md5 hash, the problem when exporting the password in Magento is that using

```
$passHash = $user->getPasswordHash();
```

Returns the password with salted md5 encryption.

Is there a way to obtain the unsalted md5 hash?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/customer One possibility would be to setup Magento not to use salt when creating passwords. May help going forward however, reversing the existing salted passwords would prove difficult as hesselbom mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll never be able to reverse the hash. There is a theoretical possibility using some kind of md5 reversing rainbow table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) but not really a stable way to do it.

Maybe an option could be if in the new system you could use the same salt as in Magento, or maybe ask your customers to enter a new password?

Comment: the problem with the other system using the same salt as magento is that the Magento salt is randomly generated so I cannot imitate that.

Comment: I managed to implement the Magento-like password hashing in Objective C and the "decrypter"